# git-pylint-commit-hook not checking all the project files

Tags: python, python-2.7, pylint

I have a python 2.7 project that has a main file *main.py* and a *src* folder containing other python files used in main.py:

```
project folder
|
+ main.py
|
+-src(folder)
   +-file1.py
   |
   +....
```

Now, I want to use git-pylint-commit-hook in order to run lint on all my python files. I installed the package using `pip install git-pylint-commit-hook`. I added a file containing

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
git-pylint-commit-hook
```

in the /project/root/.git/hooks/pre-commit folder and made it runnable.

The problem is when I commit changes, the git-pylint-commit-hook only checks main.py and does not check all the files in the src folder.

How do I fix that?

If I run `pylint` directly using parameters `*.py **/*.py` it checks all the files.

Here is what I have tried, I set the pylintrc file to set the parameters. I added a pylintrc file in the project's folder with

```
[pre-commit-hook]
params=*.py **/*.py
```

But it does not work.

How to fix the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Your setup works correctly on my environment, without requiring any *.pylintrc* file or specify any special pylint configurations. I think the hook is only checking *main.py* **because only *main.py* was included in `git add`**. Make sure that you staged the entire *src* folder and it's not git ignored, so that it will be included in `git commit`.

```
$ tree -a -L 2
.
├── .git
│   ├── HEAD
│   ├── ...
│   └── refs
├── main.py
└── src
    ├── file1.py
    └── file2.py

$ git status
On branch master

No commits yet

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git rm --cached <file>..." to unstage)

    new file:   main.py

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    src/
```

Here, `git status` is reporting that only *main.py* is staged, and *src* (and everything under it) is not yet tracked, meaning it will not be included when doing `git commit`:

```
$ git commit -m "test"
Running pylint on main.py (file 1/1)..  3.3/10.00   FAILED
************* Module main
C:  1, 0: Missing module docstring (missing-docstring)
...

------------------------------------------------------------------
Your code has been rated at 3.33/10 (previous run: 3.33/10, +0.00)
```

As expected, only *main.py* is being committed, and only *main.py* was checked by `git-pylint-commit-hook`. Once I `git add` the *src* folder, it will be included in the next attempt to commit.

```
$ git add src
$ git status
On branch master

No commits yet

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git rm --cached <file>..." to unstage)

    new file:   main.py
    new file:   src/file1.py
    new file:   src/file2.py

$ git commit -m "test"
Running pylint on main.py (file 1/3)..  3.3/10.00   FAILED
...


Running pylint on src/file1.py (file 2/3).. 3.3/10.00   FAILED
...


Running pylint on src/file2.py (file 3/3).. 3.3/10.00   FAILED
...

------------------------------------------------------------------
Your code has been rated at 3.33/10 (previous run: 3.33/10, +0.00)
```